# Guardian library can't able to generate the token

Tags: elixir, token, phoenix-framework, guardian

I'm creating an API for Signup/Sign in. I'm using guardian, "~> 1.0" to generate a jwt token for my signup. Now when I create a guardian module in my folder structure which I will show you in the code. I also passed the secret key in my cofig.ex.

Let me know If you need any other information.

Now when I try to pass this in my postman endpoint it's giving me an error

```
{
    "user": {
        "email": "siddhant24333@gmail.com",
        "password": "Radiohead",
        "password_confirmation": "Radiohead"
    }
}
```

user_controller.ex

```
def create(conn, %{"user" => user_params}) do
    with {:ok, %User{} = user} <- Accounts.create_user(user_params),
         {:ok, token, _claims} <- Guardian.encode_and_sign(user) do
       conn |> render("jwt.json", jwt: token)
    end
end
```

guardian.ex

```
defmodule DailyployApi.Guardian do
    use Guardian, otp_app: :dailyploy_api

    def subject_for_token(user, _claims) do
      sub = to_string(user.id)
      {:ok, sub}
    end

    def subject_for_token(_, _) do
      {:error, :reason_for_error}
    end

    def resource_from_claims(claims) do
      id = claims["sub"]
      resource = DailyployApi.Accounts.get_user!(id)
      {:ok,  resource}
    end

    def resource_from_claims(_claims) do
      {:error, :reason_for_error}
    end
end
```

This is the error I'm getting when I try to generate the token

```
[error] #PID<0.554.0> running DailyployApiWeb.Endpoint (connection #PID<0.553.0>, stream id 1) terminated
Server: localhost:4000 (http)
Request: POST /api/v1/sign_up
** (exit) an exception was raised:
    ** (RuntimeError) expected action/2 to return a Plug.Conn, all plugs must receive a connection (conn) and return a connection, got: {:error, :secret_not_found}
        (dailyploy_api) lib/dailyploy_api_web/controllers/user_controller.ex:1: DailyployApiWeb.UserController.phoenix_controller_pipeline/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/router.ex:280: Phoenix.Router.__call__/2
        (dailyploy_api) lib/dailyploy_api_web/endpoint.ex:1: DailyployApiWeb.Endpoint.plug_builder_call/2
        (dailyploy_api) lib/plug/debugger.ex:122: DailyployApiWeb.Endpoint."call (overridable 3)"/2
        (dailyploy_api) lib/dailyploy_api_web/endpoint.ex:1: DailyployApiWeb.Endpoint.call/2
        (phoenix) lib/phoenix/endpoint/cowboy2_handler.ex:33: Phoenix.Endpoint.Cowboy2Handler.init/2
        (cowboy) /Users/sid/dailyploy_api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_handler.erl:41: :cowboy_handler.execute/2
        (cowboy) /Users/sid/dailyploy_api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:296: :cowboy_stream_h.execute/3
        (cowboy) /Users/sid/dailyploy_api/deps/cowboy/src/cowboy_stream_h.erl:274: :cowboy_stream_h.request_process/3
        (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:249: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Also, it's showing this

```
POST /api/v1/sign_up
[debug] Processing with DailyployApiWeb.UserController.create/2
  Parameters: %{"user" => %{"email" => "siddhant24333@gmail.com", "password" => "[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation" => "[FILTERED]"}}
  Pipelines: [:api]
[debug] QUERY OK db=60.3ms queue=4.4ms
INSERT INTO "users" ("email","password_hash","inserted_at","updated_at") VALUES ($1,$2,$3,$4) RETURNING "id" ["siddhant24333@gmail.com", "$2b$12$H7f/ZygnxOzjlxMvT/FUr.pcHiMaPR.mp1WrhyLlfznZ.jWVbk0Dq", ~N[2019-07-08 11:30:59], ~N[2019-07-08 11:30:59]]
```

config.ex

```
config :dailyploy_api, DailyployApi.Guardian,
  issuer: "dailyploy_api",
  secret: "eXCQ6ZYZlPkS0p0eOoLLfkEoi0rn6O6pQ0PmhDjbElrc9G9RMQgnCMk+3kw0FHE7"
```

Comment: It's written that the secret is not found. Are you sure with your configurations? I'm not

Comment: Yes, I have written it in my config.ex file. I've generated the key using mix guardian.gen.secret.

Comment: Which configurations you're talking about?

Comment: How it’s written in your config?

Comment: Okay check it. I've edited it

Comment: I'm pretty sure from the github, that the config should have `secret_key`, not `secret`
https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian#installation

Comment: @Virviil Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo: rename `secret` to `secret_key` in your guardian configuration.

See https://github.com/ueberauth/guardian#installation.